# IO Performance of large files with Python 3, what to expect, bottlenecks?

Tags: string, file-io, python-3.x, performance

**How performant is slicing in Python 3?**
I wrote a little program that processes 7.1GB of lines of words into a cut down format (infixes).

Currently I get a processing speed of about **1.3MB/sec** on the file collection. I already  some improvements using common guides but I feel that I might be missing the real performance hog. I suspect the bottleneck in the `inFix()` function's string slicing but haven't been to find a faster solution so far.

Am I missing some important concept or is Python just not suited for such a task (yet)?

```
    def inFix(w, infixSize):
        length = len(w)
        if length > infixSize :
            surround = length - infixSize
            pre = surround // 2
            suf = surround - pre
            return w[pre:-suf]
        else: 
            return w

    def infix2g(line):
        return ("i %s %s %s\t%s\ni %s %s %s\t%s\ni %s %s %s\t%s\ni %s %s %s\t%s\ni %s %s %s\t%s\n"
                % ( inFix(line[1],1), inFix(line[2],1), inFix(line[3],1), line[0],
                    inFix(line[1],2), inFix(line[2],2), inFix(line[3],2), line[0],
                    inFix(line[1],3), inFix(line[2],3), inFix(line[3],3), line[0],
                    inFix(line[1],4), inFix(line[2],4), inFix(line[3],4), line[0],
                    inFix(line[1],5), inFix(line[2],5), inFix(line[3],5), line[0]))

    uniOut = open('3-gram.txt', 'wt', encoding='iso-8859-15')
    for line in open('3-gram-1to5_infixes.txt', encoding='iso-8859-15'):
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) != 4:
            continue
        uniOut.write(infix2g(line))
```

`uniOut.close()`

Comment: Have you tried enabling profiling and running your tool over a smaller data set? That should give you an idea as to where the greatest percentage of your execution time is going and you can optimise your code accordingly.

Comment: In the absence of profiling data, I expect it is going to be the string formatting that is causing you problems more so than the infix function.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, your best bet is to run a profiler over the script with a smaller data set to see where the time is going in relative terms.

However, there are a couple of easy optimisations you may look into as possible low hanging fruit.

Firstly, move the main processing loop inside a function in order to take advantage of optimised local variable access. This can make a surprisingly big difference.

Secondly, I would avoid the string formatting call and use a string join instead:

```
def infix2g(line):
    fragments = []
    for i in range(5):
        fragments.extend([
            'i ', inFix(line[1], i),
            ' ', inFix(line[2], i),
            ' ', inFix(line[3], i),
            '\t', line[0],
            '\n'])
    return ''.join(fragments)
```

Comment: I was actually wondering about the join function since both string formatting and the join operation were recommended for speedier operation. The optimization through local variables I did not come across so thanks for the tip.
As for performance I ended up coding this in Java which gave me about **30MB/sec**. Python seems to be lacking a performant equivalent to Java's StringBuilder class.

Comment: @Nemori: Did you even try ncoghlan's suggestion of both profiling and optimization? If others take the time to answer your question, be polite and honor their efforts.

Comment: @Nemori: StringBuilder maintains a string as a set of fragments and then joins them all together at the end when rendering the final string. Python just makes this explicit by building a listing of fragments and then joining them together.

Comment: The other thing I just noticed is that you leave both the input and output files in line buffered mode. This is unlikely to be the best choice if your goal is to maximise I/O throughput.